# THREE.JS create custom 3D shape

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, shapes

How can I create the shape below with `THREE.JS` in `WebGLRenderer`.

[image: Image of required shape]

This shape is a cube, the top face of which has been rotated 45 degrees.
Is it possible to create the cube then change it vertexes or ...
any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the vertex positions using the array cubeMesh.geometry.vertices.

```
//create a cube as per usual
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 2, 1),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()
);
scene.add(cubeMesh);

//change vertex positions
cubeMesh.geometry.vertices[1].y += 1;
cubeMesh.geometry.vertices[4].y += 1;

//indicate that the vertices need update
cubeMesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```